# Inserting Variables In MySQL Query

Tags: php, sql, mysql, variables

As you can see, I have a query I want to insert variables in.
What's wrong with my syntax?

```
$query = "UPDATE house SET epname=".$newtitle" WHERE epid= ".$epid;
```

Comment: newbie common mistake, you need to quote the string like `"UPDATE house SET epname='".$newtitle."' WHERE epid= ".(int)$epid;`, and of course you need to escape it

Comment: @ajreal-Thanks! And again you come to the rescue:)

Comment: Did you understand at last that there was 2 syntax errors - PHP one and mysql one?

Comment: Not quite-I got the php one, what is the mysql one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are your variables strings?  You will want to enclose them in quotes for the purpose of the MySQL query.

Also, you're missing a concatenation operator (period) after $newtitle.

If you echo out the value of $query, you should see the error:

```
UPDATE house SET epname=[value of newtitle] WHERE epid= [value of $epid]
```

Assuming that epname is a char/varchar value, and epid is an integer of some sort, you probably want to do this:

```
$query = "UPDATE house SET epname = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($newtitle) . "' WHERE epid= " . $epid;
```

If you do not use the mysql_escape_string function around your strings, you are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks

Comment: Thanks TehShrike! Works like a charm.

Comment: LOL! You are talking of injections and still leave $epid naked!

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Yes, I mentioned in there that I was making the assumption that $epid was an integer (in code).  Personally, I would enclose it in an intval() call to be sure.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_escape_string`, it's deprecated. Use `mysql_real_escape_string` instead, or better yet, PDO.

Answer (score 3):

The basic syntax error is:

```
…e=".$newtitle" W…
             ^^
```

If you were going to go down the route of bashing strings together to make SQL statements, then you should make use of the fact that double quotes interpolate. This results in much more readable code.

```
$query = "UPDATE house SET epname=$newtitle WHERE epid=$epid";
```

But **the approach of string bashing is flawed** . Use [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) (preferably with PDO), they are harder to create SQL injection vulnerabilities with and (arguably) easier to read.

Comment: Hi David-thanks, will make sure to do that. Can you give a brief explanation of the difference between PDO and PEAR->DB?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "UPDATE house SET epname=".$newtitle" WHERE epid= ".$epid;
```

should be

```
$query = "UPDATE house SET epname=".$newtitle." WHERE epid= ".$epid;
```

or better

```
$query = "UPDATE house SET epname= $newtitle WHERE epid= $epid";
```

Comment: Without a warning about injection or using escaping or prepared statements, this approach should not be an answer on Stackoverflow.

Comment: He asked what is wrong with his code, not how he can make it more secure. Maybe i should also talk about mysql injection or even xss for you to consider this correct, but the fact is that my answer is the exact reply for such a question.

Comment: @SpyrosP-thanks! @Konerak-I understand the importance of securing my code, but foe the sake of what I'm doing now-learning, and not developing, this is more than enough. But I will take into consideration to learn about security before getting into some serious dev.

Comment: No, he will experience another error with your code, mysql one. And, to let you know, escaping has nothing to do with injections. It's part of the syntax. Obligatory part.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel-I understand that, but don't you agree that for the sake of learning one must be able to first write any code, no matter how bad, in order to write good code afterward? I'm merely a beginner here.

Comment: Thanx for letting me know of something that is wrong. Now please take a look at what is correct : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @WideBlade there is nothing about security. These folks du not understand what are they talking about. It's just SQL syntax. Which you ought to follow. Strings must be escaped and enclosed in quotes. Numbers are another deal. With numbers you can talk of security. To protect them, you have either treat them like strings or cast to numeric type explicitly.

Comment: Shrapnel, you seriously don't have a clue about security don't you ? Escaping is a fundamental sql security measure. Really fundamental. So fundamental, that one would cry for your ignorance.

Comment: OK Guys-I'm out. Duel it off between you, I just want to code.

Comment: @WideBlade no, I will never agree with such a nonsense. These folks who answers your question out of ignorance are of that sort. They learned a few rules but understand nothing of it. Don't go their way.

Comment: @SpyrosP your answer is still erroneous. So, shut up and go learn basic mysql, lamer

Comment: Pasted from Wikipedia : The vulnerability is present when user input is either incorrectly filtered for string literal escape characters embedded in SQL statements or user input is not strongly typed and thereby unexpectedly executed. And btw, i'm a PhD student on computer security.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel-out of curiosity, where did you learn to program that you have such a strict opinion on them? Not in an offensive way, of course-just trying to understand your background for this persistence.

Comment: WideBlade, it's really a waste of time. Trust me. Just take a look at mysql injection and you will realize that his guy is totally clueless. He's the worst kind. A person with no clue about computer security that pretends to know everything while he does not know anything at all. It's really obvious, even for kids that just took up computer security. Saying that escaping does not have to do with mysql security ? lol, hilarious, best joke in years.

Comment: @SpyrosP-everybody's entitled to an opinion. I disapprove of calling people "lamers", though.

Comment: WideBlade, he didn't have an opinion. He INSISTS that what he says is correct. If i say that an orange is purple and i insist on that, how will i be called ?

Comment: @WideBlade I have just a little experience. I just do understand the very little thing: how does this darn escaping work. Where it can help you and where it can't. Do not try to understand someone's background but try to understand what are you doing.

Comment: Jesus, NOW you say that you don't understand. Then, how can you say that escaping is of no use on sql then ? AND YOU WANTED TO LET ME KNOW that escaping has nothing to do with mysql. Now, rethink of your calling me lamer and adjust this adjective to the right person.

Comment: @WideBlade go run this very query from his answer and say what result do you get. Even without escaping and security stuff. just this query with your regular data.

Comment: @SpyrosP Yeah, I've gotten the 'mysql_real_escape_string doesn't protect you from SQL injection` lecture from Mr. Shrapnel before, too. It's odd, since almost the entire Internet and the writers of the PHP documentation disagree with that.

Comment: Spyros try to read my explanations. It's not that hard to understand. You have to escape your strings despite of any dangers. Such fools like you have a funny misbelief - you all believe that only user input should be escaped. While SQL rules tells us that ANY string should be escaped, no matter of it's source. So, if you do that, there is not any danger ALREADY. All this injection blab is not because some mysterious protection faults but because stupid disobedience of SYNTAX RULES. Got it?

Comment: i'm through with you. Just believe whatever you like i don't care to help morons. What you write does not even make sense. I could even give you a live example so that you learn how escaping works, but such an utter moron as you would never even care to understand it.

Comment: yeah, i possibly helped you somewhere since you say so.

Comment: your query still unusable. that's perfect example already, my boy. no need for anything else :)

Comment: sure colonel, don't forget to include that in <?php ?> to work. It's probably the mistake that you make.

Comment: You see now, Mr. Shrapnel-you've just earned yourself a flag.